# How to add the office 365 waffle button into my own ASP.MVC app?

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online

Can I add the Office 365 App Launcher and the Bar in my custom asp.net mvc website, which is registered as an Office 365 app.

The website is also a provider-hosted app for sharepoint online.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot host the App Launcher in your own app.  You can however create a similar bar using the Office365 AppChrome control:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/javascript-controls